# Adding Tkinter Buttons to a list without .append

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm currently having a play around with tkinter trying to make my code efficient. I want to be able to index my buttons at a later date so I'm trying to put then into a list without first creating a blank list and appending them to it as I loop (The only way I currently know how to do it). I've got the below currently going on but at the moment every time the loop runs it overwrites my button at index 0 rather than appending to the list, how would I go about using something like this or use list comprehension to create my buttons?

```
for btn in range (6):
            self.Preset_Lbl = [tk.Button(self.window, width = 5, height = 1, text = mylist[0] 
            [btn], relief = "groove")]
            self.Preset_Lbl[btn].grid(row = btn, column = 1)
```

thanks in advance

Comment: You have three choices for adding to a list, and in all cases the list must exist in order to add to it: `append`, `extend`, `insert`. It's not clear why you think using those is wrong or inefficient.

Comment: You are creating a brand-new list on every iteration of the loop, overwriting whatever might have been done on a previous iteration; how could you possibly expect that to work?  Starting with an empty list, and appending to it in the loop, is exactly how you should be doing this.

Comment: Hi Bryan, I just wanted to see if I could find a solution without initially creating an empty list and appending to it, more to get a greater understanding of other ways that things can be done in Python and expand my knowledge

Comment: Hi Jason, I'm not sure how I could possibly expect it to work? I wasn't aware I was overwriting my list every time I iterated, therefore that is why I asked the question on here

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In contrast to the comments, you can indeed create a list variable and initialize all its values in the same line as such without needing to loop through it (It does use a for loop inside the implementation, but it's reduced to one line and without using the function `append()` directly):

```
self.Preset_lbl = [tk.Button(self.window, width=5, height=1, text=mylist[0][btn], relief="groove") for btn in range(6)]
```

You need to decide for yourself, if you care about the readability of this approach or you can also check if it would impact performance in any way by profiling/benchmarking it like stated by Roland Smith.

Comment: Thank you for the solution, will keep in mind about readability and performance never really thought about it that way. Thanks again

Answer (score 3):

> trying to make my code efficient

In general, you should only bother to optimize code after it has been proven (by *measurements*, i.e. through profiling) that it is a major bottleneck. In general for a GUI the creation of a window and filling it with widgets is a one-time event. So it is unlikely to be the most inefficient code in the program.

First, optimizations can often make code more complicated and difficult to read and understand. For example, for the programmer `stopbutton` is pretty much self explanatory. If you referred to the same object as `buttons[0]` it would not be clear what that button is supposed to do.

Second, you don't know what the bottlenecks in your code are before you measure them.
For example, in my `stl2pov` program, it turned out that [*string formatting* was actually consuming most of the time](http://www.erewhon.home/programming/profiling-python-scripts-1-stl2pov.html). And using the appropriate type specifier to the format string *halved* the necessary time.
[Another example](http://www.erewhon.home/programming/profiling-python-scripts-5-ent_without_numpy.html) is where replacing `statistics.mean` with `statistics.fmean` reduced the runtime by about a third.